# Application gets killed during camera/file intent Xiaomi Android API 29

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera

I'm having a little bit of an headache with several applications in Kotlin - Compose; I'll go straight to the point:

### Context

The issue is consistently happening (9 times out of 10) with Xiaomi devices running API 29. The device that I currently have available (and that also presents that issue) is a Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite.

**Emulator**: Running the application in an emulator (API 29) works without any problem

**Manifest:** Manifest has the following permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

**Provider paths:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-cache-path
        name="my_files_cached"
        path="." />

    <files-path
        name="my_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Runtime permissions:** Runtime permissions are given in both camera & file picker components when clicking a button (see code snippets in Code section).

### Issue

1. In the app start a launcher for either
   `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()` or
   `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()`
2. While outside of the app, either in the camera or in file picker, logcat writes out `--- PROCESS ENDED (16504) for package ... ----` signaling that the app has been killed in the background
3. Snap a photo or select a file and when returning to the app a white screen is shown for atleast 3-4 seconds and then it's clearly visible that the application has been recreated. Other than that, the content (file or photo) is not returned properly to the app (or in the camera case, not returned at all).

### Code

Below a snippet of a `@Composable` body for handling the Camera photo snapping (I'm not posting the file picker code to avoid a text-wall; consider that it's similiar to the camera one):

```
val tmpFile = createTmpExtCachePhoto(photoFileName)

val context = LocalContext.current
var currentPhotoUri by remember { mutableStateOf(value = Uri.EMPTY) }
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    Objects.requireNonNull(context),
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", tmpFile
)

val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
    onResult = { success ->
        if (success) currentPhotoUri = uri
    }
)

val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // Permission Accepted: Do something
        cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
    } else {
        // Permission Denied: Do something
        onCameraPermissionDenied.invoke()
    }
}


if (currentPhotoUri.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
    onImagePicked.invoke(currentPhotoUri.toString())
}

Button(
    modifier = modifier,
    colors = buttonColors,
    onClick = {
        // Check permission
        when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) -> {
                // Permission already given, perform operation
                cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
            }
            else -> {
                // Asking for permission
                launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text(text = buttonLabel)
}
```

### Situation

From what I got I think that there shouldn't be a particular issue within my codebase and this whole ordeal seems like it's coming from the system beneath that kills the app immediatelly after it goes out of focus.
Now, if that happens to be the case, how should this situation be handled? Is there something that I can do to solve the problem? I'm willing to evaluate even workaround solutions that gets the app into a stable and reliable situation.

With that being said, thank you for your time!

Comment: "when returning to the app a white screen is shown for atleast 3-4 seconds" -- that sounds like a Compose performance issue. Do you see the same delay when using a build type that uses R8? "the content (file or photo) is not returned properly to the app (or in the camera case, not returned at all)" -- we don't know what "not returned properly" means, especially for the case where you didn't provide the code. You probably should be leveraging `rememberSaveable()` more to retain data across the brief process termination.

Comment: It is normal that an app can get killed when it is in the background. I assume the battery saving features of your tested device is rather aggressive in closing app.s When you return to your app, the last opened activity will be shown. Consider restructuring your app so that it can handle this case.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderHoffmann, I'll try to have a look at that but I'm considering this option more of a "workaround" solution in case that there are no other ways.
@CommonsWare I'll definitely try build type using R8; however, consider that when I launch the camera, and while still in the camera, logcat shows that the process has been killed so I was thinking that the white screen was related to the activity recreation more than to a compose performance issue; if the activity gets recreated would `rememberSaveable` still be useful in this case?

Comment: @x-devel: "I'm considering this option more of a "workaround" solution in case that there are no other ways" -- there are many more scenarios for this than simply launching the camera. Your process can be terminated at any point when it is not in the foreground, such as the user navigating to another app via HOME, RECENTS, or a notification. What you consider "a workaround" is what Android developers consider to be core functionality.

Comment: "I was thinking that the white screen was related to the activity recreation more than to a compose performance issue" -- I don't know how much of your time is related to the fresh process, app functionality (e.g., stuff kicked off by `Application` `onCreate()`), or compose performance. All can be contributing. You will need to determine that for yourself; I merely suggested one way of alleviating one potential cause for the issue. "if the activity gets recreated would rememberSaveable still be useful in this case?" -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your time and I apologize for the confusing usage of the word "workaround": since this issue is consistently presenting itself with Xiaomi devices running API 29 I thought that perhaps there was a more particular solution for the problem that didn't have anything to do with the application codebase itself. If it was happening sporadically then I would've considered the workaround solution a normal solution (which it is) but since in this case the issue is sistematically happening with a specific brand-API combo I thought that maybe there was something else to be done

Comment: How aggressive a device is about terminating background processes varies and is dependent on things like OS version, amount of system RAM, what else is also consuming RAM in the background (and what those processes are doing), and how much RAM the newly-foreground process takes. So, perhaps your Xiaomi devices have limited system RAM, or perhaps they use the same (or similar) camera app that consumes a lot of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CommonsWare and Alexander Hoffmann comments I ended up solving the problem by making use of what the Android framework and Compose already gives us in terms of handling and persisting state throughout system-initiated process death:

- [rememberSaveable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?hl=en#restore-ui-state) for persisting data in Composable components;
- [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-savedstate?hl=en#savedstatehandle) in ViewModel for persisting StateFlows; this I found particularly useful and ended up allowing me to completely solve the issue putting my application in a very stable and reliable state.

[This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) is a very useful page on developer.android that I heartily recommend. It describes the various possibilities that we have when talking about saving UI states.

With that being said I hope that this will be useful and thank you all once again for your time!